# Bevel shader not working (Bevel Node)

Tags: shaders, bevel

I'm trying to use the bevel shader on an experimental mesh, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, everything seems to be in place but the bevel itself does not work! [image]

Comment: maybe try a lower Radius value, like 0.2? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: i tried every radius possible, this is the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1an9x0K7" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1an9x0K7/)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a split normals problem, go into the *Object Data > Geometry Data* and click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*, then lower down the node's *Radius* value. Don't forget to switch to *Rendered* preview. Also the *Bevel* node only works in Cycles.

[image]

Comment: i really appreciate you helping me, i tried your solution but had no luck, i have a 1650gtx, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: problem fixed, i was in the wrong preview mode - Switched from material preview to Render and now it shows, thank you my man

Comment: oh ok nice I was searching for the solution

Comment: I suggest you to post the solution as an answer so that you can mark it as the solution to your question, people can upvote it, and the next people having the same issue will easily see the solution.

Comment: @  L0Lock, The problem was the split normals, as I said, but he couldn't see the result because of the preview mode